# Updating from one database to another SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to figure out how to update a table. At the minute I have it truncating the table then inserting all the records back into it(as shown below).

What I want to achieve is that it only updates new records so if a record is deleted from DATABASE2 it is still held in DATABASE1.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [DATABASE1].dbo.[TABLE1];

INSERT INTO [DATABASE].dbo.[DB1]
   SELECT * 
   FROM [SERVER2].[DATABASE2].dbo.[TABLE1];
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: even you get out of the insert issue, you will still wont be able to get only the 'new records' since there is no condition specified.All the data will e copied.hope you understand what am coming to say !

Comment: "but if I delete a record it dissapears from the DATABASE1"?? Of course it will. What else do you expect?

Comment: I dont think we have something useful here !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me re-clarify what you want to archive, basically you want to refresh the data from server2, if it has the new value.

If yes, then do not directly delete everything in table1

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [DATABASE1].dbo.[TABLE1];
```

instead, switch to

```
DELETE FROM [DATABASE1].dbo.[TABLE1]
INNER JOIN [SERVER2].[DATABASE2].dbo.[TABLE1] ON /* primary mapping here*/
```

with this you will only delete all the records exist in server2.

then, for your insert statement

```
INSERT INTO [DATABASE].dbo.[DB1]
SELECT X.* 
FROM [SERVER2].[DATABASE2].dbo.[TABLE1] X
LEFT JOIN [DATABASE].dbo.[DB1] Y ON /* primary mapping here*/
WHERE Y.{primary key} IS NULL
```

So those records that missing in server1 will not touched, remain whatever there are.
The rest of data being refresh.